# How to deal with many input fields with the same name, and post to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, data-oriented-design

Let's say that I have an HTML structure that looks like this. Each left-context-field and right-context-field are related and in the backend it should be possible to link left to its right colleague.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="First left value">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="First right value">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="Second left value">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="Second right value">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="Third left value">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="Third right value">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="Fourth left value">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="Fourth right value">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*and* a user can add as many additional rows as they please. How would I go about posting the values to a PHP file?

Should I wrap all rows in one single huge form, and then call `.serializeArray()`? Or one form per row?

From a data-oriented approach, what's the best way to deal with this? I'll be sending the data to the back-end, but I want to make the data ass easily accessible for the the backend developer as possible.

Comment: I've Edited meda's Answer, but he is not approving that Edit, So I've posted a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've Edited meda's Answer, but he is not approving that Edit, So I'm posting it here again.**

In HTML forms the way you send arrays is using brackets.

For example

```
name="values[]"
```

like this.

```
<form name = 'vals_form' action = 'php_page.php' method = 'post'>
  <table>
    ... <!-- Your all code -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="First left value" name="values[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="First right value" name="values[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Post Values' />  
  </table>
</form> <!--and close the form tag-->
```

In PHP you get the array back

```
$values = $_POST['values'];
```

Comment: Note: apparantly wrapping only the rows is invalud. You'll have to wrap the whole table in the form. But how do you now send the form to PHP?

Comment: `form's attribute action` specifies that where should go this `form` when `Post Values` button is clicked. in this scenario, it will posted to `action = 'php_page.php'` --- `php_page.php`. Make sure you've added a button inside the `form` to send this  `form` with attribute `type = submit`, otherwise you'll have to use `jQuery` to `post` stuff to backend

Answer (score 1):

In HTML forms the way you send arrays is using brackets.

For example

```
name="values[]"
```

like this.

```
<form name = 'vals_form' action = 'php_page.php' method = 'post'>
  <table>
    ... <!-- Your all code -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="left-context-field" value="First left value" name="values[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="right-context-field" value="First right value" name="values[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Post Values' />
  </table>
</form> <!--and close the form tag-->
```

In PHP you get the array back

```
$values = $_POST['values'];
```

Comment: And how would you then post these forms to PHP?

Comment: you need to create a `form` tag around the `table` and need to post that `form` on `button click`

Comment: @MubinKhalid From a semantic HTML perspective, is it best to wrap the whole table, or only all the rows?